# phpldapadmin expand users list produces error

Tags: phpldapadmin

When hitting the + symbol next to users after logging into ldapphpadmin the error

```
There was a problem with the request
```

is produced and, in the log, the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1024001 bytes) in /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/AJAXTree.php on line 100
```

I have updated the `memory_limit` and restarted the apache service but the error persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the error persist with the exact same 'Allowed memory size' number as before? If so, the memory_limit is probably being set from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the same error is repeated. I have updated all of the php.ini I could locate. Also, there are two php.ini listed. One is listed in /etc/php5/apache2./php.ini and also in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. The memory_limit one in the cli php.ini is set to -1. If I change it to a MB value the structure in the phpldap admin changes from a single list to a different organization.

Comment: Where are the other locations a php.ini could be (i listed and changed all via locate cli command) or that memory size is being referenced? 

Also, I did not set this up. The problem was set in my lap and I am trying to resolve it. PHPLDAPAdmin is 1.2.0.5 version

Comment: You might be looking for `/etc/phpldapadmin/apache.conf`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you ever so much!